# How to get value list in another def

Tags: python

**Hello everyone,**

I'm a newbie in Python, I have a question is there is any way to get the results like below:

```
def value_domain():
    domain = ['extasiatny.us', 'chestecotry.us', 'uygulamatcccbm.com', 'piketuojaqk.us', 'oltratoke.ru', 'dstek-herzaman-destek.com']
    for x in domain:
        return x

def condition_rules():
    z = 6
    for x in range(100):
        if z + x == 10:break
        print(f"""<condition component="Network" condition="contains" property="Url" value="{value_domain()}" />""")
    else:
        print("Finally finished!")

condition_rules()
```

This is current results:

```
<condition component="Network" condition="contains" property="Url" value="extasiatny.us" />
<condition component="Network" condition="contains" property="Url" value="extasiatny.us" />
<condition component="Network" condition="contains" property="Url" value="extasiatny.us" />
<condition component="Network" condition="contains" property="Url" value="extasiatny.us" />
```

I wanna get the results like this:

```
<condition component="Network" condition="contains" property="Url" value="extasiatny.us" />
<condition component="Network" condition="contains" property="Url" value="chestecotry.us" />
<condition component="Network" condition="contains" property="Url" value="uygulamatcccbm.com" />
<condition component="Network" condition="contains" property="Url" value="piketuojaqk.us" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
domain = ['extasiatny.us', 'chestecotry.us', 'uygulamatcccbm.com', 'piketuojaqk.us', 'oltratoke.ru', 'dstek-herzaman-destek.com']
def value_domain():
    i=0
    for i in range(len(domain)):
        x=domain.pop(0)
        return x

def condition_rules():
    z = 6
    for x in range(100):
        if z + x == 10:break
        print(f"""<condition component="Network" condition="contains" property="Url" value="{value_domain()}" />""")
    else:
        print("Finally finished!")

condition_rules()
```

---

```
<condition component="Network" condition="contains" property="Url" value="extasiatny.us" />
<condition component="Network" condition="contains" property="Url" value="chestecotry.us" />
<condition component="Network" condition="contains" property="Url" value="uygulamatcccbm.com" />
<condition component="Network" condition="contains" property="Url" value="piketuojaqk.us" />
```